# Excel Find the Nth Non Blank Value in Column

Tags: excel

I want to look at a column and return the Nth Non-blank value. For the most part, I will only want to return the first 15 non-blank values.

The below question has an answer that almost works for me, but I can't figure out how to modify the formula:

[How to get nth non-blank column in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449722/how-to-get-nth-non-blank-column-in-excel)

The formula finds the 3rd to last non blank value in a column:

```
 =INDEX(A1:A202,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A202)/(A1:A202<>""),3))
```

I thought the modification would be easy to just find the 3rd value, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone please help me modify this and help explain to me what this formula is doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have **Excel 365** and if your data is in column **A** and *N* is in cell **B1**, try the following:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),B1)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The `INDEX()` function can accept a dynamic drop down formula just like a column of cells.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula.

```
=INDEX(Data,SMALL(IF(Data<>"",ROW(Data)-MIN(ROW(Data))+1),C1))
```

`Data` is the column range from which you want to return the nth non-blank value. You can replace the name with a hard-coded address.

C1 = holds the value for n.

The formula is adapted from *ExcelJet* where it's advertised as an array formula (confirm with Ctl + Sift + Enter) but on my Excel 365 it works as a normal formula.

Comment: Your formula returns the row number.  To return the contents of that cell, use your formula as an index into `Data`.  eg  `=index(data,SMALL(IF(Data<>"",ROW(Data)-MIN(ROW(Data))+1),C1))`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This works. I'm trying to take the average of all these numbers and when there's not a value for let's say the 10th value, the cell returns a #NUM! error and the average wont calculate. How would I go about changing the formula so that i could avoid that error and be able to calculate the average?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, I was hasty in posting. Once the perceived problem was solved I forgot to do the easy part. I've corrected my formula.

Comment: @AndyJensen That is a different problem than what you have posted. I suggest you mark one of the answers as correct, and then post a new question with your actual problem.